# Yii2, few tables with uncomfortable generic field names for 1 Model

Tags: activerecord, architecture, yii2

I'm building REST++ service with Yii2, which should be able to deal with 2 table schemes, (databases storing ~the~same~ data):

1. **a_new_one**, which is perfect to be handled with ActiveRecord;
2. **the_old_one**, which has 1 generic table 'Object' with columns like 'field1', 'field2', etc, and few additional tables.

I want my request methods and controllers to be all the same for both schemes (would be very great, really). That means, that I need to have THE SAME MODELS for both cases.

The troubles all relate to **the_old_one** database:
Let's say data of model User is stored in tables **Object** and **UserProfile**. If I make 2 ActiveRecord classes for both tables, will it be possible to make hasOne() relations to them in 3d class **User** (not sure about inheritance here), so it can be manipulated like this:

```
$user = User::find()->someFilters()->someOrderingAndPagination()->one();
$user->Name = $your_new_name;
$user->Age = $why_not_90;
$user->save();
// and so on.
```

Because I really don't want to be forced to write it like this:

```
$user = User::find()->notSureAboutRelations()
    ->filters()->ordering()->pagination()->one();
$user->object->field7 = $your_new_name;
$user->userProfile->Age = $why_not_90;
$user->save();
```

I learned, **Doctrine** has easy model mapping ($user->Name can be mapped to db's Object.field7), but it's still impossible to map to 2 different tables within 1 Entity. Or am I incorrect ? If so, would it be a good idea to use Doctrine within Yii2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finished with idea to have the same controllers and models. Only URLs remain the same.

The old db Model data could be gained this way:

```
$user = User::find()
  ->select([
    'Object.field7 as Name',
    'UserProfile.Age as Age',
    // ...
  ])->from('Object')
  ->join('UserProfile', ['UserProfile.ObjectId = Object.Id'])
  ->andWhere('User.Id' => $id);
```

And it's an ugly mess up when saving this models. Cos you need to assign a lot of fields in BEFORE_INSERT, BEFORE_UPDATE events.